# order by alphabet PHP, MySql but list the letter before each group

Tags: php

Say I had a table with :

```
First      | Last
-------------------
Bob          Dylan
Ashley       Scott
Lol Cats
black cake
```

It would order them but do

```
A:
  Ashley Scott
B:
  Bob Dylan
  Black Cake
L:
  lol cats
```

I know how to list by abc from MySql. but i want to have it put the letter before each group of names. So i can make a nice looking interface, and at the top of the page have A B C D letters at the top that went contacts#letterL

I know how to do the #links in a url. Its just the div Id. I know how to grab from MySql. The part i'm not sure on is echoing the letter before the group of names that start with that letter.

I was thinking of getting the first letter of the name of saving it in a variable.

```
if ($lastletter == $currentleter) {
  echo name
} else {
  $lastletter = $currentleter;
  echo '<div id="Letter ' . $currentleter .  '" class="letterheader">' . $currentleter . '</div>';
}
```

Not sure if this idea would be a efficient idea. Would this be the right away of doing this?

Comment: Your question is solely presentation layer -- PHP in this case.  To be clear, if the letter isn't in the list of results, you don't want to show it (ie: the missing C - K)?

Comment: Yeah. If the letter is not, don't show. I was thinking about also adding each new letter to a array to generate the quick jump letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code but something like this should work:

```
$currentleter = substr($name , 0 , 1);
if ($lastletter != $currentleter){
    echo '<div id="Letter' . $currentleter .  '" class="letterheader">' . $currentleter . '</div>';
    $lastletter = $currentleter;
}

echo $name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the records with order by first name.

```
$sql = "select * from tblname order by firstname";

$lastletter = "A";

echo $lastLetter;
if ($lastLetter != substr($firstname, 0,1))
echo $lastLetter;

echo $firstname;
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty good solution except IDs must not have spaces in them so you wanna change

`<div id="Letter ' . $currentleter .  '" class="letterheader">` to

`<div id="Letter_' . $currentleter .  '" class="letterheader">`.